# converting string to datetime in C# on null value exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I use the below code

```
 extensionRequest[i].EndDate = DateTime.Parse(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ActualEndDate"].ToString());
 extensionRequest[i].ExtendedEndDate = DateTime.Parse(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ExtendedEndDate"].ToString());
 extensionRequest[i].ReceivedDate =Convert.ToDateTime(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["dReceivedOn"].ToString());
```

this works fine when values are coming from the DB
but when `NULL` values are returned it throws an exception!!

Should i check values for all three values like the code below

```
if (dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["dReceivedOn"].ToString()==null){
extensionRequest[i].ReceivedDate="";
}
else{
extensionRequest[i].ReceivedDate =Convert.ToDateTime(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["dReceivedOn"].ToString());
}
```

or i should assign all dates to null on exception?!

is there any other way to do in single line? like `tryparse` or something?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953941/datetime-parse-converting-string-to-datetime-format-equals-to-datetime-field-in?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I'll try being creative. You can create a `Nullable TryParse` as an `Extension Method` edition:

```
public static DateTime? TryParseNullable(this DateTime dateTime, string val)
{
    DateTime outValue;
    return DateTime.TryParse(val, out outValue) ? (DateTime?) outValue : null;
}
```

and then use:

```
extensionRequest[i].EndDate = DateTime.TryParseNullable(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ActualEndDate"].ToString());
```

and that can be your one liner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTime.TryParse()` method which returns `true` on successfull conversion otherwise returns `false`.

Note: calling `ToString()` on `null` throw `NullReferenceException` hence you need to check for `null` value before conversion.

Try This:

```
 if(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ActualEndDate"] != null)
    DateTime.TryParse(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ActualEndDate"].ToString(),
                                             out extensionRequest[i].EndDate);
```

Comment: if dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ActualEndDate"] is null calling ToString will throw execption

Answer (score 1):

You can check if value is null like this

```
extensionRequest[i].EndDate = Convert.IsDbNull(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ActualEndDate"]) ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ActualEndDate"]);
```

I'm sure `.ToString()` is not required.

It will be more readable if you cache a row to the local variable:

```
var row = dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i];
...
extensionRequest[i].EndDate = Convert.IsDbNull(row["ActualEndDate"]) ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["ActualEndDate"]);
```

Be sure `.EndDate` and others allow null values. In other words, that is `DateTime?`